# jquery loading issue in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am new to angular 2. Currently I am facing the issue with loading of jQuery in my app.

Here is my example code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Jobkeeper</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/forms.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/assets/frontend/custom/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/assets/frontend/custom/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
     <link href="app/assets/frontend/custom/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="app/assets/frontend/custom/css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="app/assets/frontend/custom/css/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/assets/frontend/custom/css/main.css">
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300,600italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="app/assets/frontend/custom/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="app/assets/frontend/custom/js/jquery.toaster.js"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="app/assets/frontend/custom/js/jquery.toaster.config.js"></script>    

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    {{ Html::script('core-js/client/shim.min.js') }}
    {{ Html::script('zone.js/dist/zone.js') }}
    {{ Html::script('reflect-metadata/Reflect.js') }}
    {{ Html::script('systemjs/dist/system.src.js') }}
    {{ Html::script('systemjs.config.js') }}

    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app></my-app>

<script src="app/assets/frontend/custom/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var owl = $("#owl-demo");

        owl.owlCarousel({

            // Define custom and unlimited items depending from the width
            // If this option is set, itemsDeskop, itemsDesktopSmall, itemsTablet, itemsMobile etc. are disabled
            // For better preview, order the arrays by screen size, but it's not mandatory
            // Don't forget to include the lowest available screen size, otherwise it will take the default one for screens lower than lowest available.
            // In the example there is dimension with 0 with which cover screens between 0 and 450px

            itemsCustom: [
                [0, 1],
                [450, 1],
                [600, 2],
                [700, 2],
                [1000, 3],
                [1200, 4],
                [1400, 6],
                [1600, 6]
            ],
            navigation: true

        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

When I load/refresh the page, the owl carowsel not initialising because the jQuery is not loading on that time.

*I have did some possible solutions:-*

> 1. I have placed the jquery(owl carowsel code) in angular footer directive.
> 2. Aslo I have import the jquery file in app.module.ts but it was not working.

So how it could be work. Please let me know.

Comment: no, the problem is your html does not exists at that time, plus you should avoid using jQuery with angular 2. messing with the dom directly may create unexpected behavior

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but our design is totally based upon jQuery and we really need it for our design.

Comment: okay but the problem is still that `$("#owl-demo").length` is `0`...